# git branch ahead and behind for local branch?

Tags: git

`git branch` will show ahead and behind

```
  master    03ea915f82 [behind 16] test
```

I think it means `master` is behind 16 of `remote/origin/master` ?

Is it possible to show ahead and behind between local branches?

For example, I have `master` and `develop`, I often update `master` then `rebase master` in `develop`, it would be help if it shows something like this:

```
  master    03ea915f82 test
  develop   1231231231 [behind master 16] test
```

Comment: You sure you want it? I've seen instructions on how to accomplish this but know that simple commands such as `git pull` will now also consider that remote branch. In other words, if you are on develop and issue a git pull, you will pull from master.

Comment: `rebase master in develop` ... this makes no sense to me.  Typically, you would rebase `develop` on `master`, and then fast forward the latter with the former.

Comment: `git merge-base master develop` ... this would at least show you the most recent common ancestor commit.  You could then count how many commits are between this and the tips of the `master` and `develop` branches.  This would give you an idea of how rough the rebase might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `git branch` will show ahead and behind
>
> ```
> master    03ea915f82 [behind 16] test
> ```
>
> I think it means `master` is behind 16 of `remote/origin/master` ?

It's not possible to tell from this alone.  The count(s) is/are for whatever is set as the *upstream* for branch master.  With `-vv`, the name of the upstream is included:

```
$ git branch -vv
* master          e0688e9b2 [origin/master: behind 479] git svn: fix
  stash-exp       8dbdf339c [origin/master: ahead 1, behind 1142] st
```

Note that both branches here have `origin/master` as their upstream, but `stash-exp` is more behind than `master` is (and `stash-exp` is also *ahead* 1).

> Is it possible to show ahead and behind between local branches?

Yes—but you get only *one* upstream per branch.  If you set the upstream of local branch `A` to local branch `B`, you see only how far ahead or behind `A` is with respect to `B`, and not to `origin/A`.

You can compute your own counts.  What both `git branch` and `git status` do here is to run (the internal equivalent of) `git rev-list --count`:

```
$ git rev-list --count stash-exp..origin/master
1142
$ git rev-list --count origin/master..stash-exp
1
```

These are the two counts `git branch -vv` printed.  We can get both at once:

```
$ git rev-list --count --left-right stash-exp...origin/master
1       1142
```

Note the three dots here, which produce a *symmetric difference*: commits reachable from either branch tip, but not from both branch tips.  The `--count` code in `git rev-list` counts the two separately when using `--left-right`, and prints the left hand side count (1) on the left and the right hand side count (1142) on the right.  Swap left and right sides and the counts swap:

```
$ git rev-list --count --left-right origin/master...stash-exp
1142    1
```

If I wish to find the relationship between two local branches, such as `master` and `stash-exp`, I can use those here:

```
$ git rev-list --count --left-right master...stash-exp
663     1
```

which tells me there are 663 commits reachable from the tip of `master` that are not reachable from the tip of `stash-exp`, and 1 commit reachable from the tip of `stash-exp` that is not reachable from the tip of `master`.