# Git fetch not working as expected ":gone]" is not being added to branch description

Tags: git, github

If we execute `git fetch -p` or `git fetch --prune` it will prune branches if deleted on remote.

After executing this command if we do `git branch -vv` it suppose to show `: gone]` for the local branches which are deleted from remote.

In my case sometimes it is working as expected but not always. Sometimes it is not adding `: gone]` to the branches deleted on remote.

My goal here is to delete branche if local branch is deleted on remote.

I am wondering why this is happening ?

Comment: I am also interested in this question. I have an unsatisfactory alias (to output local branches which lack a remote counterpart) that I'd love to replace one of these days (`git config --global alias.brloc '!git branch -vv | grep -v origin; git branch -vv | grep gone'`).

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily *wise* to delete your branch named X just because someone else deleted his branch named X.  If you're working on a new feature and you called it `feat`, and Bob gave up on his new feature that he was calling `feat` and Bob deletes Bob's `feat`, that doesn't mean you should delete your `feat`!

That aside, let's look at a special feature of branches.  This special feature is *only* available for (local) branches, not for things like `origin/master`, which parts of Git call *remote-tracking branches* and which are listed under `git branch -r` output.<sup>1</sup>  They actually have several special features—for instance, you can get "on" a branch using `git checkout`, as in after `git checkout master`, the `git status` command will say `on branch master`.  But that's not the special feature I mean here.

The special feature we care about here is that they can have an *upstream* setting.  That is, your `master` can have one—and only one—upstream, and your `develop`, if you have a `develop`, can have one upstream, and your `feat`, if you have one, can have one upstream, and so on.  Your choice here is to have an upstream, or not have an upstream.  You make this choice one branch at a time, for each branch.

To *take away* the upstream setting of a branch, use `git branch --unset-upstream name`.  The branch named *`name`* now has no upstream.  If you leave out the *`name`* part, it applies to the *current* branch, i.e., the one to which your `HEAD` is attached.  This is not the *only* way to unset it, but it's usually the *best* way.

To *set or change* the upstream setting of a branch, use `git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream name`.  The branch named *`name`* now has an upstream; the upstream is has is the argument you gave as *`upstream`*.  As with `--unset-upstream`, leaving out *`name`* means the current branch (you're not allowed to leave out *`upstream`*).  Likewise, this is not the *only* way to set it, but usually it's the *best* way, because the `git branch` command will verify whether the *`upstream`* argument is sensible before it lets you set it.

Sometimes branches have an upstream setting [right from the get-go](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/from-the-get-go), and sometimes they don't.  We'll look at when and why in a moment.

---

<sup>1</sup>I've gotten to the point where I try to avoid the word *branch* for the remote-tracking things.  I now just call *remote-tracking names*, because they're so different from local branch names.  Note that `git fetch -p`, or `git remote prune origin`, or setting `fetch.prune` to `true`, affects only these *remote-tracking names*.

---

#### What exactly is an upstream?

An upstream is just another branch name—and here, by *branch* name, I mean *either* a local branch like `master` or `develop`, *or* a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`.  So you can have the upstream of `develop` set to `master` if you like, or to `origin/master`, or to `origin/develop`.  The `git branch --set-upstream-to` operation will let you set anything that exists and, to Git's mind, makes sense here.

Git has a weird flaw of sorts here.  Part of this is historical.  Back in the ancient past, Git did not have *remotes*—there was no `origin`—so Git did not have remote-tracking names either without `origin`, there could be no `origin/master`.  But part is due to the simple fact you may or may not *have* an `origin/xyz`, and `origin/xyz` could even *go away* while you're hard at work on your `xyz` branch (because Bob *thought* you were done and went and deleted `xyz` over on origin).

The flaw is, to put it a bit *too* simply, that the upstream you've set—back when it existed and `git branch --set-upstream-to` therefore let you *set* it—might be gone now.  And that's the case when you see `: gone` in your `git branch -vv` output.  At some point in the past, you told *your* Git that *your* branch `xyz` should have `origin/xyz` as its upstream, and `origin/xyz` existed at the time.  So `git branch` verified that all was good and made the setting.  But now the name is gone, so the setting is no longer valid and `git branch -vv` makes note of that.

In fact, the upstream setting of a branch is built out of two parts, and you can configure either or both parts with `git config`, or even bring your configuration in your chosen editor (`git config --edit`) and mess with them directly:

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

This setting, in this particular repository, says that the upstream of `master` is `origin/master`.  You might think you can just take the `origin` part from the `remote =` line and the `master` part from the `merge =` line, but this is a sort of trap: there's a secret complicated mapping.  To find the upstream setting of some branch, use `git rev-parse` with the `@{upstream}` suffix:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{upstream}
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This works for branches whose upstream is set to be another local branch too.

Anyway, because it *is* two parts like this and you *can* mess with it outside the normal `git branch --set-upstream-to` mechanism, you can *break* the upstream setting.  If you do break it—if you set it to something nonsensical—`git branch -vv` will list the upstream as "gone", using the same technique as when normal, everyday Git operations break it because it really *did* go away.  Git does not care *why* it's broken, only that it is or is not broken right now: if it is broken right now, Git says "gone" and otherwise pretends it's unset.

Note that this also means that if Bob *accidentally* removed `xyz` from `origin` and Bob fixes his mistake and puts `xyz` *back*, your Git can go from "gone" to "not gone, everything is fine" after another `git fetch`.  That's yet another reason you should not have your Git remove your local branch just because someone messed with some *other* Git somewhere else.

#### What good is an upstream?

The upstream setting only offers a few minor features.  Sometimes, some people *really like* these features, but they're never *required*.  So in one sense, an upstream is no good at all.  You don't *have* to use them, *ever*, provided you avoid `git pull`.

The features, though, are:

- Easier push: the standard `push.default` setting *requires* that your branch have an upstream *if* you want to run `git push` without extra arguments.
- Easier merge and rebase: the `git merge` and `git rebase` commands can use it.  The `git pull` wrapper, which you don't have to use ever and which I recommend *avoiding* anyway, require an upstream.  The wrapper first runs `git fetch` for you, and then immediately—before you have a chance to decide whether it's a good idea based on what `git fetch` did—runs `git merge` or `git rebase` for you.
- More-useful `git status`: the first line of `git status` tells you whether you're in detached HEAD mode, and if not, which branch you're on.  Having an upstream means that there's a *second* line, right after the one about the branch you're on, when you're on a branch.  The second line compares the branch to its upstream and tells you whether it is "up to date" with its upstream.

So that's what an upstream is good for: it makes some things easier and/or more useful.  But you are limited to *one* upstream at a time.  You may, sometimes, want to get the equivalent of the `git status` second-line output for some arbitrary pair of names.  There is a way to do that using `git rev-list --count`, but we'll leave that for [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51482412/1256452) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408509/1256452).

#### Why do some branches already have an upstream set, and others don't?

There are lots of ways to *create* branches in Git.  Each one does something a little bit different from its other alternatives—which is why each of these methods *exists*, but also gives you this profusion of confusion.

The two main commands for creating new branches are `git branch` and `git checkout`.  When you use `git branch` to create a new branch, *you* are in full control at all times:

```
git branch --track newbranch origin/upstreamname
```

or:

```
git branch --no-track newbranch origin/upstreamname
```

Despite the upstream being called *upstream*, the argument controlling it is spelled `--track`—another historical accident or mistake, really.

If you don't use `--track` or `--no-track` here, `git branch` uses whatever you've chosen as a default when you configured `branch.autoSetupMerge`.  See below for what that means.

When you use `git checkout`, you *can* use `--track` or `--no-track`, but if you don't use *either* option, it gets more complicated.  The `branch.autoSetupMerge` setting still matters but ... well:

- `git checkout -b newbranch` creates *`newbranch`*, but creates it from `HEAD`, so it doesn't set an upstream.  That is, the new name *`newbranch`* now identifies the same commit that `HEAD` identified just before this.
- `git checkout -b newbranch origin/name` creates *`newbranch`* and creates it using `origin/name`.  That is, the new name *`newbranch`* now identifies the same commit as `origin/name`.  This obeys your `branch.autoSetupMerge` configuration.

  `git checkout -b newbranch existing-branch` creates *`newbranch`*, using *`existing-branch`* as its starting point.  That is, the new name and the existing name now identify the same commit.  This also obeys your `branch.autoSetupMerge` configuration, but see below for why I separated this out.
- `git checkout name` *either* uses an existing *`name`*, *or* creates a new branch named *`name`* using `origin/name`.  If it creates a *new* branch, it obeys `branch.autoSetupMerge`.

  Note that this will never create a new branch using a local branch name, i.e., it can't make a local branch that has another local branch as its upstream.  If that were going to be the case, the two *`name`*s would be the same, so the branch by definition already exists, so it just checks out the local branch without creating anything.
- `git checkout --track origin/name` creates a new branch named *`name`* and *does* set its upstream.
- `git checkout --no-track origin/name` creates a new branch named *`name`* and makes sure it has *no* upstream.

So, as you can see, it's complicated!  The exact method of creating the branch determines in part whether it has an upstream, with the rest of the determination being based on your `branch.autoSetupMerge` configuration.  This setting has three possible values:

- `true`: set the upstream when the starting-point is a remote-tracking name.
- `false`: don't set the upstream.
- `always`: set the upstream when the starting-point is *either* a remote-tracking name *or* a (local) branch name.

The default, if you did not set `branch.autoSetupMerge` at all, is to pretend you set it to `true`.  So *by default*, all of these branch-creating options act like you said `--track` *if* you give them an `origin/*` name, or any other remote-tracking name, as their starting-point.  That's true even if the starting point is merely *implied*, as in the:

```
git checkout develop
```

case where you don't *have* a local `develop` but do have a remote-tracking `origin/develop`: this *creates* your new local `develop` *from* your remote-tracking `origin/develop`, and if `branch.autoSetupMerge` is `true`—including if you haven't set it at all—now your `develop` "tracks"—has as its upstream—your `origin/develop`.

#### Summary

Some of your branches have upstreams set.  Which branches have upstreams, and what those upstreams are, is up to you, controlled by your configuration and/or by your command-line options and/or by additional `git branch --set-upstream-to` or `git branch --unset-upstream` commands.

Those branches that *do* have upstreams set will get some useful features.  If the upstream that *is* set "goes away" by whatever process, `git branch -vv` will list your local branches *and* say that their upstream is "gone".  Other Git commands will just pretend you unset their upstream.  If the upstream comes back again, the upstream will resume its usefulness.

Deleting a local branch *only* because its upstream is gone is a mistake.  Deleting it because *you* are *done with it* is fine.  You don't *need* to have a local branch named `develop`, or even one named `master`, if you're done with them, *even if they still exist as upstream `origin/develop` or `origin/master` names*.  You can just use `origin/master` to refer to your Git's memory of the `master` on `origin`—you don't *need* to have your own `master` at all.

Sometimes, you are done with a branch *because of* some underlying reason that also means that the upstream is going to be gone, or is already gone.  In that case, deleting your local branch is fine—you're deleting it **because you're done with it**.  The fact that it will be deleted on `origin`, or already has been deleted on `origin`, is irrelevant here!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This is really helpful. In my use case I want to delete local branch if its upstream is gone. In my use case upstream is gone means I am done with that particular branch and I do not need that branch anymore.